# Conditional Rendering on Items of Native Base Picker [React Native]

Tags: react-native, picker, native-base

I’m using ‘Native Base’ components for our product and going good with this,
but I’m stuck at one point and it is around putting Items in Nativebase Picker. My code is like this

Render Method code -

```
render(){

  return (

      <View style={{marginTop: 20,  flexDirection:'row', flexWrap:'wrap', justifyContent:'space-around', alignItems:'center'}}>

        <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'flex-end' }}>
          <Button
             style={{ backgroundColor: '#6FAF98', }}
             onPress={this._showDateTimePicker}

             >
             <Text>Select Date</Text>
          </Button>
        </View>

        <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'stretch'}}>
          <Picker
              style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#2ac', alignSelf:'stretch'}}
              supportedOrientations={['portrait','landscape']}
              iosHeader="Select one"
              mode="dropdown"
              selectedValue={this.state.leaveType}
              onValueChange={(value)=>this.setState({leaveType:value,})
                //this.onValueChange.bind(this)
              }>

              <Item label="Full Day" value="leave1" />
              {
                this.showStartDateFirstHalf() // Here I want to show this picker item on the basis of a condition 
              }
              <Item label="2nd half" value="leave3" />
         </Picker>
        </View>
        <DateTimePicker

          isVisible={this.state.isStartDatePickerPickerVisible}
          onConfirm={this._handleDatePicked}
          onCancel={this._hideDateTimePicker}
          mode='date'
        />

      </View>



    );


}

showStartDateFirstHalf()
{
    if(!this.state.isMultipleDays)
    {
      return(
          <Item label="1st Half" value="leave2" />
      );
    }
}
```

So, this code is working fine if `this.state.isMultipleDays` is false, But when `this.state.isMultipleDays` is true, it means when it is in `else` part then i'm getting this error -

[`Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKAfl.png)

Comment: When I'm trying to return 'null' in else part of "showStartDateFirstHalf()" method then it is showing cannot read property 'prop' of null.

Comment: Does that work when the code is moved outside the <Picker /> component and you render <View /> instead of <Item />

Comment: Can we see the source code of Picker please?

Comment: if I do like then it works for "else" part but Empty Item is created - 

showStartDateFirstHalf()
    {
        if(!this.state.isMultipleDays){
          return(
              <Item label="1st Half" value="leave2" />
          );
        }
else{
      return(
              <View></View>
          );
}
    }

Comment: If I try to code all items out in a separate method as follows then this does not work at all. 
fillItems()
{
  return(
    <View>
      <Item label="Full Day" value="leave1" />
      <Item label="1st Half" value="leave2" />
      <Item label="2nd half" value="leave3" />
    </View>
  )

}

Comment: @Dan
I've used this Picker by Native-Base

https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#Picker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's an easier answer to this. Instead of creating the separate showStartDateFirstHalf() function try this:

```
render() {

  const pickerItems = [
    {
      label: 'Full Day',
      value: 'leave1',
    },
    {
      label: '1st Half',
      value: 'leave2',
    },
    {
      label: '2nd Half',
      value: 'leave3',
    },
  ];

  const filteredItems = pickerItems.filter(item => {
    if (item.value === 'leave2' && this.state.isMultipleDays) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });

  // The 'return' statement of your render function
  return (
    ...
    <Picker ...>
      {(() => 
        filteredItems.map(item => 
          <Item label={item.label} value={item.value} />
      )()}
    </Picker>
    ...
  );
}
```

That way, you already have a list of items that is determined before the `return` statement of the render cycle. Also the use of `filter` instead of `map` will not just give you `null` as the second item if the condition is not met, but will remove the item altogether.

Comment: Thanks It worked for me. 

A little improvement I did to make it work for me.

<Picker ...>
            {
              filteredItems.map(item => <Item label={item.label} value={item.value} />)
            }
       </Picker>