# React Native - Filter native base Picker Item based on condition

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to skip a specific account from picker item , So i have passed the account to be skipped into the child component from parent , But its generating error saying

```
 error occured:TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: second argument to Function.prototype.apply must be an Array-like object (evaluating '[].concat.apply([],t.children)')
```

I have refered the solution provided on this 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105014/conditional-rendering-on-items-of-native-base-picker-react-native).
I have From account and To account drop down , i want to skip the selected from accounts from the To accounts drop down.
This is my child component

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Picker, Icon } from "native-base";
import { Dimensions, Platform } from "react-native";

export default class accountsDropDown extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        console.log('skipped Acct:'+JSON.stringify(this.props.skipAcct))
        let filteredItems = null ;
        if(this.props.accounts !== undefined && this.props.accounts.acctId != null){
            filteredItems = this.props.accounts;
        }

        if(filteredItems != null && this.props.skipAcct !== undefined && this.props.skipAcct.acctId != null){
            filteredItems = filteredItems.filter(acct=>{
                return acct.acctId == this.props.skipAcct.acctId ? false :true;
            })
        }

        console.log('filteredItems:'+JSON.stringify(filteredItems))
        return (
            <Picker
                selectedValue={this.props.selectedValue}
                mode="dropdown"
                iosHeader="Choose To Account"
                style={{ width: Platform.OS === "ios" ? undefined : Dimensions.get("window").width }}
                iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
                onValueChange={value => this.props.onValueChange(value)}
            >
                {filteredItems != null &&
                    filteredItems.map(acct => {

                        return <Picker.Item key={acct.acctId} label={acct.desc} value={acct} />;
                    })}         
            </Picker>
        );
    }
}
```

This is my parent component

```
<View style={styles.item}>
                            <Text note>From Account</Text>

                            <AccountsDropDown
                                selectedValue={this.state.fromAcct}
                                accounts={this.state.xferSrcAccts}
                                navigation={this.props.navigation}
                                onValueChange={itemValue => this.setState({ fromAcct: itemValue })}
                            />
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.item}>
                            <Text note>To Account</Text>

                            <AccountsDropDown
                                selectedValue={this.state.toAcct}
                                skipAcct = {this.state.fromAcct}
                                accounts={this.state.xferDestAccts}
                                navigation={this.props.navigation}
                                onValueChange={itemValue => this.setState({ toAcct: itemValue })}
                            />
                        </View>
```

Comment: [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not return anything. If you want to return an array of Picker Item you should use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead.

Comment: changed to map , the issue still exist

Comment: do you see which line the error is coming from? on a side note, instead of this `let filteredItems = null` use `let filteredItems = []`. The problem is if for some reason there is no accounts data came (could be server issue or so) `filteredItems` will remain `null` and your user will experience a crash. Best would be if you destructure `this.props` with default/initial values then you can basically write `const { accounts: [], ... } = this.props` and it will allow you omit the first `if` block and make the code more cleaner and less error prone

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by changing the render method like below

```
    render() {
        console.log('skipped Acct:'+JSON.stringify(this.props.skipAcct))
        let filteredItems = [] ;
        if(this.props.accounts.length > 0){
            filteredItems = this.props.accounts;
        }

        if(filteredItems != null && this.props.skipAcct !== undefined && this.props.skipAcct.acctId != null){
            filteredItems = filteredItems.filter(acct=>{
                return acct.acctId == this.props.skipAcct.acctId ? false :true;
            })
        }

        console.log('filteredItems:'+JSON.stringify(filteredItems))
        if(filteredItems.length >0){
                return (
                    <Picker
                        selectedValue={this.props.selectedValue}
                        mode="dropdown"
                        iosHeader="Choose To Account"
                        style={{ width: Platform.OS === "ios" ? undefined : Dimensions.get("window").width }}
                        iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
                        onValueChange={value => this.props.onValueChange(value)}
                    >
                        {filteredItems.map(acct => {                    
                                return <Picker.Item key={acct.acctId} label={acct.desc} value={acct} />;
                            })}         
                    </Picker>
                );
            }
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, `Array.length` can be used. But this doesn't match the question. Edit your question to match the solution you were trying to get.

Comment: I still don't understand `acct.acctId` being `boolean` and later used as a `key`.

Comment: @its4zahoor : its not an assignment operation ,its conditional operator ,  filteredItems.filter(acct=>{
                return acct.acctId == this.props.skipAcct.acctId ? false :true;
            })

Comment: acct.acctId == ? Isn't it assignment

Comment: @its4zahoor : oh sorry , but its working as i expect , could you please correct me on that line , how it should be written instead of the current line ?

Comment: Tell me what are you trying to do in that line?

Comment: initially the filteredItems contains the all the accounts , including the account to be filtered , so am trying to filter the current filtered array and filter out the accounts with acctId not equal with the passed skipAcct.acctId

Comment: Change it to `.filter(acct => acct.acctId !== this.props.skipAcct)`, no need for { braces too.